# Get table size filtered by a certain value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to know the size in MB or KB for each table but filtered by a certain value. In my case the value is the user id where each table has that column.

So i tryed this:

```
SELECT table_name AS "Table", 
round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) AS "Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = "myDBname" AND table_name IN ("co_user", "user")
```

It works fine, but it gives me the entire size value for each table. Now i need to get the value of each table but only for the rows where user id is a certain value.

```
AND user_id = 'userIDvalue'
```

Is it possible? How can i do it?

I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Thank you.

Comment: Is `user_id` taken from both tables?

Comment: Yes user_id is in every table. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Information like this is not stored in `information_schema`. What you can do is, to take the result you have right now and multiply it with

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE user_id = 'userIDvalue' / SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i would not have an exact result, or even approximate!

Comment: Then why are you doing this at all? And just that there's no misunderstanding, that's not the fault of the query in my answer. It's the information stored in information_schema which is not always up to date. You can of course do an `analyze table your_table;` first. This updates the statistics of the table. Then you'll be pretty close. And in general, even without optimizing or analyzing, information_schema is not that far off.

Comment: Well i need to set a limit to database usage for each user. So i need to know how much db space user is using. That's it.

Comment: You can have a look at partitioning tables. Then you can limit space on operating system level.